# How to add file into every folder?

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command

I need to add a file into every folder that contains the file `header.php` in it via command line.  The name of the file I need to add into every folder is called `topscripts.php`.

I've been searching for different ways to do this but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  For example, one command I tried added `topscripts.php` into every single folder instead of just the ones that contained `header.php` in it...

Can anyone help out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find -type f -name 'header.php' | xargs -n 1 dirname | xargs -n 1 cp -f topscripts.php
```

Answer (score 0):

`@echo off`

`for /D /R C:\testdir\ %%a in (*) do (`

```
if exist %%a\header.php (

    echo found header.php in %%a
    echo copying topscripts.php to %%a...
    copy C:\testdir\topscripts.php %%a\topscripts.php
)
```

`)`